# Multiple instances of Sinatra::Base applications with different configurations

Tags: sinatra, rack

I developed a Rack application based on `Sinatra::Base`. Now I would like to use many instances of it, each with a slightly different configuration, in a single Rack application.

My `rackup` should look like

```
use Rack::Lint

map '/mel' do
    run Site.new('/home/mel/site').app
end

map '/pub' do
    run Site.new('/pub').app
end
```

The `Site` class collects various parameters (in this example only the root dir) and does some preparatory work. The `#app` method should return a `Server` object that holds a reference to the served `Site` instance.

This is an example of the `Site` and `Server` code:

```
class Site
    def initialize(root_dir)
        @root_dir = root_dir
        # ... set up things ...
    end

    def app
        # This is where a new Server Rack application should be created
        return Server.new { |server| server.set :site, self }
    end
end

class Server < Sinatra::Base
    before do
        @content = settings.site.all_files
    end

    get /(.*)/ do |url_path|
        # do things...
    end
end
```

The problem with this code is that the `#app` method does not return a valid Rack application.

What should I do in `#app` to return a new, configured `Server` Rack application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to make it work suggested by "carloslopes" on #sinatra.

The `Site#app` method becomes

```
class Site
    def app
        # This is where a new Server object should be created
        return Server.new(self)
    end
end
```

and the `Server` objects get their parameters via instance variables:

```
class Server < Sinatra::Base
    def initialize(site)
        super()
        @site = site
    end

    before do
        @content = @site.all_files
    end

    get /(.*)/ do |url_path|
        # do things...
    end
end
```

**Edit**: made community wiki so that other can make the solution even better and share the credit.